# Collatz chain recursive function C

Tags: c, recursion, collatz

I am trying to create some code that when given a starting number attempts to find the length of the corresponding collatz chain.

I was hoping to do this recursively and this is what I have so far :

```
#include stdio.h

int collatz(int number, int count)
{
    if(number == 1)
    {
        return count;
    }
    if(number%2==0)
    {
    number = number/2;
    collatz(number, count+1);
    }
    else
    {
    number = number*3+1;
    collatz(number,count+1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int stored=0;
    int temp;
    for(int i = 1;i<10;i++)
    {
        temp = collatz(i,1);
        if(temp>stored)
        {
            stored = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n",stored);
}
```

The problem is of course that the function eventually reaches its endpoint, but then gets returned as the length of the chain and this becomes the new number..

How can I structure this program so that when the count reaches its endpoint I can take this value as the output of the very first call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of the recursive call.  Right now you're ignoring the value of the recursive call and returning 0.  Each recursive call should look like this:

```
return collatz(number, count+1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just staying on the same topic, that has worked perfectly but I am a bit confused why I get segmentation fault when I use integers, but when I replace all integers by 'long long' it runs fine. Do you know why? I changed the loop variable to iterate up to one million.

Comment: What happens if `number` becomes an odd number larger than 715,827,882?